# Problem creating virtual directory in Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, yii2

I have an Yii2 project which has been working fine with apache with the following settings:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/test/backend/web/"
    ServerName test.local

    <Directory "/var/www/html/test/backend/web/">
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . index.php
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /api /var/www/html/test/api
    <Directory /var/www/html/test/api>
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . index.php
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Now I need to migrate to Nginx. I have been able to figure out the configuration for the main web site.
But for the '/api' virtual directory, if anything is added after '/api/' in the URL, the request is redirected to the main index.php instead of the one in api directory.
My current Nginx setting is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/test/backend/web/;
    index index.php;
    server_name test.local;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
    }

    location /api {
            root /var/www/test;

            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            }

            location ~ /\. {
                    deny all;
            }
    }
}
```

I have also tried ~ ^/api but still no luck.

Comment: You need to use `location ^~ /api { ... }`

Comment: It's the same with location ^~ /api { ... } 
For example test.local/api/v1/users/create does not match this location.

Comment: Your `try_files` statement should specify `/api/index.php` in the last parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `root` directive in the `server{}`.
The working config is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php;
    server_name test.local;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
            root /var/www/test/backend/web/;

             location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            }

            location ~ /\. {
                    deny all;
            }

    }

    location /api {
            root /var/www/test;
            index index.php;

            try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.php$is_args$args;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            }

            location ~ /\. {
                    deny all;
            }
    }
}
```

Also as [Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith) mentioned

> Your try_files statement should specify /api/index.php in the last parameter.